# NServiceBus DBMS connection timeout

Tags: oracle, nservicebus

I use Nservicebus with Oracle Queues OAQ instaed of MSMQ. 
I have a problem working with a dbms server that is shutdown every day at the same time. 
In particular when my nservicebus host can't get the dbms connection it starts logging on. 
When the dbms is restarted my host restart or not randomly! However restarting my host everything is ok!

Another detail is that when my nservicebus host can't restart it logs a 'connection timeout message' every 15 seconds!

What's the behavior of NserviceBus when it's reading from a queue and the dbms crash? What could i do to solve this problem?

thank you,
R

Comment: if they are on the same machine perhaps make your NSB service dependent on the "Oracle Queues OAQ" service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the problem you're facing is the result of the design of your system. By having the queues in the DB, when the DB becomes unavailable, so do the queues. NServiceBus assumes that it is always able to communicate with its queues, as is the case when using a distributed/federated queuing system like MSMQ.

You can look at what some people in the community have done to combat this same problem when they were using IBM MQ (http://code.google.com/p/nservicebuswmq/) - ultimately falling back to MSMQ under those conditions and then syncing back up with MQ when it came back online.